# log4net not logging debug statements

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using log4net for the first time and have followed the documentation using supplied configuration samples, however debug statements do not log.

Info, Error, Warn and Fatal levels all log correctly. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

app.config:

```xml
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />

<log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">

        <mapping>
            <level value="INFO" />
            <foreColor value="Green"/>
        </mapping>

        <mapping>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <foreColor value="Cyan,HighIntensity"/>
        </mapping>

        <mapping>
            <level value="WARN" />
            <foreColor value="Purple,HighIntensity"/>
        </mapping>

        <mapping>
            <level value="ERROR" />
            <foreColor value="Red,HighIntensity"/>
        </mapping>

        <mapping>
            <level value="FATAL" />
            <foreColor value="Yellow,HighIntensity"/>
        </mapping>

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
            <conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%file:%line) - %message%newline" />
        </layout>            
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="example.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Some people have mentioned checking AssemblyInfo for [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()], however there is no difference with or without this line.

Logger is declared like:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger( typeof( CWD_Netsuite ) );
```

and is accessed like:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
log.Debug("Debugging");             //does not get logged
log.Info( "Entering Application" ); //logged to console and log file
log.Debug( "Debug Statement" );     //does not get logged 

log.Error( "Error statement" );     //logged to console and log file
log.Warn( "Warning statement" );    //logged to console and log file
log.Fatal( "Fatal Statement" );     //logged to console and log file
```

Comment: Just to clarify all the below answers, in the Log4Net logging hierarchy, DEBUG is the lowest, below INFO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have a filter set to `INFO` level in your root category (thus filtering out any messages of `DEBUG` level):

```
<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
</root>
```

Change it to

```
    <level value="DEBUG" />
```

Answer (score 13):

The log4net levels are defined in the following order:

ALL,
DEBUG,
INFO,
WARN,
ERROR,
FATAL,
OFF

Based on your current settings you are writing everything with INFO and below.

Set your root node to the following:

```
<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 10):

Change the level value to "DEBUG" in your  node...

```
<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
</root>
```